# Как сохранить аргумент метода объекта от первого вызова?

Tags: javascript

Почему теряется obj.number(5)?

```
var obj = {
    number: function (value) {
        this.myNumber = []; // Создал ключ с массивом в качестве значения
        this.myNumber.push(value); // При каждом вызове метода number, в массив записывается значение его аргумента
        return this;
    }
};

obj.number(5).number(10);

console.log(obj)
```

Хотелось бы видеть результат `myNumber: [5, 10]`, но в итоге выводиться такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

потому что вы и массив обнуляете при каждом вызове

```js
var obj = {
    number: function (value) {
        if(!this.myNumber){
            this.myNumber = []; 
        }
        this.myNumber.push(value); 
        return this;
    }
};

obj.number(5).number(10);

console.log(obj.myNumber)
```